# Where is endpoint to monitor tasks on agents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I am wondering where can I find the Mesos rest api endpoint documentation. In my on prem Mesos 0.28 + Marathon version, I can get the statistics from endpoint http://agent.com:5051/monitor/statistics.json
But in my aws dc/os installation, I couldn't get the statistics. Actually, all the endpoints are different in DC/OS and on prem mesos. In my AWS dc/os , the url is http://masterIP/mesos/state, in on prem mesos, it's http://master:5050/state. I wonder where I can get the docs about endpoint definition?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference in this context is a DC/OS system component called Admin Router, [dcos/adminrouter](https://github.com/dcos/adminrouter), and from its documentation you should be able to see the mapping to vanilla Mesos (and Marathon, etc.) from DC/OS endpoints and vice versa.